# Single Page Website .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory, redirect

Let's see if I can explain well the situation. I have a **single page website** with all the content in screen, but hidden. If, peg, you go to *domain.com/product/about* I'd take the first part to go to div-column "product" and div-row "about", **with some Javascript and CSS positioning**.

**The problem:** I need my .htaccess to rewrite **all** URLs (except index.html ofc) to index.html (or whatever URL we set).

**The problem inside the problem:** this webpage is in a subdirectory, and it could -probably- be in a second level subdirectory (that is, *(root)/folder/subfolder/thisweb*). Let's see with this last case, so it'll be easier to go up than down.

**What I have:**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /folder/subfolder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.html
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L]
```

**What happens:**

- domain.com/subfolder/foo: Redirects to domain.com/folder/subfolder/
- domain.com/subfolder/foo/: *The requested URL /er1csports/test/foo/ was not found on this server.*

*Playing around with other rules, sometimes I was redirected to parent's folder index.html. Just like if the RewriteRule didn't worked at all - **JFYI**.*

**What I need:**

- Rewrite, as I said, everything to index.html, **without changing the URL** in address bar - it shouldn't matter the sublevels of the URL (*foo/foo2/foo3* should also rewrite to index.html).
- Images, CSS, Javascript, resources in general, if they could be not affected with their URL and references it would be great.
- Whatever the URL is, "folder" should never appear in the URL address bar. *If I could be told how to hide too the "subfolder", if the rules applied were different in both cases, would be also great*.

I know**,** a lot of things. But I hate .htaccess and I've been searching and messing around for hours and I've been not able to find it.

I'll keep on searching and trying, but what I don't want is to write 100 lines when there's a way to write only 10 and keep it clean.

**Thanks a lot for your help and time!**

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder/subfolder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, domain.com/subfolder/foo is not found, and redirects to domain.com/folder/subfolder/foo/. Maybe a .htaccess from pattern folders could be messing out things?

Comment: Above .htaccess will apply for URLs such as: `domain.com/folder/subfolder/foo` (your URL doesn't have `folder/` before `subfolder` However yes .htaccess present in parent folders will indeed change its behavior.